Android MessagingStyle notification uses cached icon, sets same shortcutID
I am currently working on an app that displays various blog posts in a news feed. The user can choose to receive notifications once a day with new posts from authors he subscribed to (the logic to send notifications is managed on the server which sends requests to Firebase).
The requirement is to show the notification in MessagingStyle on Android, such that Person object represents the author. The title is always the same ("Subscription feed").
When several notifications arrive at once, I often observe a wrong icon shown for the author (the one from another author; sometimes all authors look the same). The text is correct, however.
Each time a notification arrives, the app downloads the icon. It is saved in the cache, but not permanently as a file on device (perhaps this is wrong?). When I set the image to a Person, I have verified (by looking at the pixels and the generated ID) that i set a correct one - but on the device I see a wrong one displayed. Here is some code.
fun createMyNotification(message : MyMessageClass) {
    val notification: MyNotification = message.getNotification()
    val toast = notification.toast
    val personBuilder = Person.Builder()
    val personName: String = toast.title
    personBuilder.setName(personName) // this is used as shortcutID by the system!

    // Get the already downloaded author icon from my cache using unique id
    // I have verified by looking at generationID and pixels the image here is correct
    val customIcon: Bitmap = downloadManager.getCachedBitmap(toast.getIconName(), pushId)
    val profileImage = IconCompat.createWithBitmap(customIcon)
    personBuilder.setIcon(profileImage)
    val person = personBuilder.build()
    
    val chatStyleNotification = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(person)
    val locus = LocusIdCompat(messageKey) // tried to create a unique ID, not used in production code
    val shortcut = ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, personName)
        .setIcon(profileImage)
        .setPerson(person)
        .setLongLived(true) // without this the image in notification is not shown (?)
        .setShortLabel(personName)
        .setLocusId(locus) // this line changes nothing
        .setIntent(<intent created elsewhere>)
        .build()

    // add text
    val textMessage = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(toast.getContent(),
        System.currentTimeMillis(), person)
    chatStyleNotification.addMessage(textMessage)
    
    // Here I logged shortcut.id and i see the title (author name) is used as id!
    
    builder.addPerson(person).setShortcutInfo(shortcut).setStyle(chatStyleNotification)
    ShortcutManagerCompat.pushDynamicShortcut(context, shortcut)
}

From the documentation, the system uses shortcutID associated with the MessagingStyle notification to correlate it with the info inside the app or in other places. I have seen that this shortcutID is, in fact, is the notification title (= author name), which surprised me, as I thought it should be unique, while different people can have same names in a messenger. I cannot change this id and the titles in my used case are the same ("Subscription feed").
I strongly suspect this causes the observed behaviour. The system uses the image it has somehow cached for this shortcutID, ignoring the one I set. When I use different titles for notifications, I don't get duplicate author images.
My questions: what can I do? :D Do I need to store the author images locally as a file instead of downloading them? (There can be hundreds of authors...) Does this behaviour (using personName as shortcutID, ignoring the image I set) look like a bug which should be reported (if so, where)? Any other ideas how to get correct images displayed?
